# Is "prohibit" a negative word?

Tags: technical, double-negation

I encountered the word *prohibited* in some software documentation and am curious if this is an example of a double negative:

***Prohibit requests for PROHIBITED parts***

(This is an option in a piece of software; names omitted to protect the guilty.)

I found the wording confusing, though it sorta makes sense because I know that "PROHIBITED" is a type of status for parts in this system. I'm mostly curious from an educational POV.

**Question**: Is *prohibit* a negative word?

(This word must've been invented by a Marketing department: "because *disallow* sounds too negative!")

Follow-up question #1: Is there a better term for *negative word* in this context?

Follow-up question #2: Is there a[n exhaustive] list of *negative* words, or a guideline for identifying words as such?

By *negative word* I mean words such as **not** and **no**, and that can result in double negatives when used in a sentence.

Comment: prohibit (v.) early 15c., from Latin prohibitus, past participle of prohibere "to hold back, restrain" (see prohibition). Related: Prohibited; prohibiting. from etymonline, "prohibit" The word has it's positive connotations ie, protective.

Comment: It sounds a little weird, but there's nothing wrong syntactically or semantically with "Prohibit requests for PROHIBITED parts", since "requests" and "parts" are two different types of entities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, "prohibit" is grammatically a negative word, since it allows *any* forms and negative polarity items in its complement.  "They prohibited us from swimming anywhere." "My uncle prohibited my mother from giving me a red cent." ("a red cent" in the non-literal interpretation appears only in negative contexts)

However, there is no rule in English against having several negative words appearing together.

Comment: Except that it doesn't always improve comprehension to have several negatives around. That's not grammatical, though; you're right.