# Is "prohibition against," a double negative?

Tags: double-negation, negative-polarity-items

"Prohibition against stealing," was the phrase that was being used. I get what the speaker was trying to say, but I'm just wondering if it is grammatically correct or if it could have been worded better.

Comment: Nothing wrong with "prohibition against stealing" and certainly no double negative. "Prohibition on stealing" would also be correct and, to my ears, would sound better.

Comment: Well, nobody is taking the hint. A double negative would be "There **isn't no** prohibition against stealing"

Comment: 'Support for' means 'support extended to'; the preposition is needed to connect 'support' with the thing supported (the referent of the prepositional complement). The suitable preposition with 'prohibition' are 'against' and 'on'.

Comment: This isn't a double negative, but also double negatives are not grammatically incorrect.

Comment: It might be closer to a tautology - the _against_ seems to be redundant since you can't have a prohibition _in favour_ of something. Writing without the preposition, you could say a _stealing prohibition_, but that's a bit clunky. I think the _against_ is just a common proposition used with this noun.

Comment: The "negatives" in "double negatives" refer to specific polarity items, not words like "prohibition" that are negative in a semantic sense.

Comment: @anomaly: I see what you're trying to say, but the term "double negative" includes the negative polarity item *plus* whatever is licensing it, and "prohibition" and "against" do both license NPIs -- consider e.g. "[a general prohibition against anyone entering the city of Cairo](https://books.google.com/books?id=jH-57_-auocC&pg=PA23&dq=prohibition+anyone)" -- so they really can be part of double negatives.

Comment: @ruakh: Thanks, that's a good point.

Comment: @ruakh For me a double negative is an expression which, looked at from a mathematical, formal logic or data processing point of view reverses itself. For instance "Don't you not do that!" Which in speech is emphatic but in data processing would result in the action being taken. I can't see that "prohibition against" has that quality of self-reversal. I agree with Oscar Bravo that, if anything, it is tautological.

Comment: @BoldBen: I think you misunderstood my comment. I didn't argue that "prohibition against" is a double negative, only that something like "a general prohibition against \*no one entering the city of Cairo" would be.

Answer (score 24):

> A double negative is a grammatical construction occurring when two forms of negation are used in the same sentence.
>   [- wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_negative)

Your example isn’t a double negative because there aren’t two forms of negation in your quote. There isn’t even one form of negation in the quote.

Syntactically, *prohibition* is not a negated term. To be a negated form, it would need to be something like *non-prohibition*.

Likewise, *against* isn’t a negated term. It is just a preposition to relate the word *prohibition* to the thing prohibited.

Comment: well, a double logical/semantic narrative...

Comment: in-hibition could be a morphological negative

Comment: @Carly: the “in-” in “inhibit” is not actually the negative prefix, but the homophonous prepositional prefix.

Comment: It's like how "to kill someone murderously" is also not a double negative, though in that particular example one might argue it utilises a delightful poetic redundancy.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It's scary that that's the first example you came up.

Comment: @automaticallyGenerated My brain is scary :)

Answer (score 11):

“Prohibition against” is not a "double negative" (or rather, it isn't an example of negative concord)*. Compare “a battle against”. Even though the preposition “against” often is used to express that something acts counter to something else, it is not a negation.

As other answers mention, the word “prohibit” also does not contain any morpheme explicitly dedicated to negation. But “prohibit(ion)” does have some connection to negation in that it can license a [negative polarity item](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarity_item) like “at all”: we can say “they are prohibited from driving at all” while most speakers can’t use *at all* in a sentence like *“they are permitted to drive at all”. (See Greg Lee's answer to "[Is “prohibit” a negative word?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/230351/is-prohibit-a-negative-word)")

The [Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=prohibition+*_ADP&year_start=1800&year_end=2009&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cprohibition%20%2A_ADP%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bprohibition%20of_ADP%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprohibition%20against_ADP%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprohibition%20in_ADP%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprohibition%20on_ADP%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprohibition%20by_ADP%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprohibition%20as_ADP%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprohibition%20from_ADP%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprohibition%20upon_ADP%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprohibition%20for_ADP%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprohibition%20with_ADP%3B%2Cc0#t2%3B%2Cprohibition%20*_ADP%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bprohibition%20of_ADP%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprohibition%20against_ADP%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprohibition%20in_ADP%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprohibition%20on_ADP%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprohibition%20by_ADP%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprohibition%20as_ADP%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprohibition%20from_ADP%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprohibition%20upon_ADP%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprohibition%20for_ADP%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprohibition%20with_ADP%3B%2Cc0) indicates that “against” is the second most common preposition found after “prohibition”. The most common is “of”; you could say “prohibition of stealing”. Other possibilities are “prohibition on” and “prohibition from”.

[image: Google ngram viewer chart showing frequencies of "prohibition" plus any adposition between 1880 and 2008. "prohibition of" is the most frequent, at between 0.000250% and 0.000325%. "prohibition against" is the next most frequent, at between 0.000025% and 0.0000110%. Below that in descending order are "prohibition on", "prohibition in", "prohibition as", "prohibition from", "prohibition by", "prohibition for", "prohibition upon", and "prohibition with".]

---

*"Double negative" is a fairly ambiguous term: it is often used to refer specifically to a construction that is excluded from the grammar of standard English ("I don't have no money" = "I don't have any money"), but a sentence like "I **didn't** say that he **didn't** come" has two negative words corresponding to two separate negations, which is completely permissible in standard English. I prefer the term "negative concord" to refer to the phenomenon seen in "I **don't** have **no** money" = "I don't have any money"; another benefit of the term "negative concord" is that it doesn't specify a particular number, since we can see more than two negative words in a sentence with concord: "I **didn't** tell **nobody nothing**" = "I didn't tell anybody anything."

Comment: Isn't the whole point of a true double negative that it is ungrammatical because it leads to an ambiguity: _I don't have no money_ is understood colloquially to mean _I don't have any money_, however semantically, it actually means _I have some money_ (being without money would mean _I have no money_, and I've stated I don't have that, so I am not without money). So there is an ambiguity.

Comment: @OscarBravo: Being ambiguous doesn't make something ungrammatical. Standard English has many ambiguous constructions: for example, [prepositional phrase attachment and conjunction scope](https://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=27691). Negative concord is ungrammatical in standard English because the people who established the standard decided to exclude it.

Comment: (The "people" I referred to in my last comment consist of speakers and writers with social influence from various eras; I don't mean to say that there was a single moment where this decision was made, or a single identifiable group responsible for it. But the categorization of negative concord as "ungrammatical" is definitely a social convention: this judgement is not just an inevitable consequence of the way that the rest of English semantics works.)

Comment: @OscarBravo: "I don't have no money" does *not* "actually" mean "I have some money." No native speaker would understand it to mean that in regular, everyday speech (at least, not to the exclusion of the negative form). Language is a tool for communication, not a system of formal logic. Words and sentences mean what they are commonly understood to mean, no more and no less.

Comment: @Kevin I'm not sure I agree actually, whether the negative form is excluded might depend on context or even emphasis. For example, how would you interpret someone saying "I don't have *no* money"; someone replying to "Do you really have no money?" with "I don't have no money" (perhaps with the previous stress on the *no*); or clarifying with "I don't have no money but I don't have loads either"?

Comment: @Kevin You're assuming everyone is onboard with the colloquial phrase. I could imagine many native speakers, who'd had a very formal education for example, being perplexed by this statement. It means what it means when parsed using the formal rules of language. Adopting a colloquial meaning is fine but beware misunderstandings and ambiguities.

Comment: @OscarBravo: Re "the formal rules of the language" - [Fred Jelinek](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frederick_Jelinek) said it best: "Every time I fire a linguist, the performance of the speech recognizer goes up."

Answer (score 2):

A double negative?  No.  It's not even a single negative.  Neither "prohibition" nor "against" is a negative. Examples of negatives include but are not limited to:

- no
- not
- nothing
- nobody
- nowhere
- none

A negative in grammar expressly contradicts what the negative is modifying so as to indicate an absence of existence.

To be clear, "prohibition" is the positive action of some authority imposing a rule that bars a thing or activity.  "No prohibition" would be a negative because it would indicate the absence of existence of prohibition.  Likewise, "against" is a preposition that positively situates the relative positions of the subject of the preposition and the object of the preposition. "Not against" would be a negative because it would indicate the absence of that situation.

"The helmet failed against the crushing weight of the brick falling on it from ten stories up."  In that sentence, you may view "failed" in a negative light, but it's not grammatically negative because it is indicating the positive action of the helmet caving in instead of performing the positive action of resisting or repelling the crushing weight.  Likewise "against" positively posits the crushing weight in relation to the helmet.  Were it "The helmet failed not against the crushing weight..." that would be a negative.  Were it "Not the helmet failed against the crushing weight..." that would be a negative.  A double negative would be, "It wasn't the helmet that didn't fail," which would be wrong if the meaning were suggesting that the helmet failed but something else didn't.

Comment: There's semantic negation (or really negativity) in both words.  (But they don't actually logically convert to a single positive.)

Comment: There is no absolute semantic negativity in "against". "Against" is just a connector.  "The shovel is leaning against the wall" doesn't mean that the shovel is opposed to the wall and wants to knock it down. Sometimes "against" just indicates a relationship between objects, or a direction "against the grain, not with".

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not a double negative. "Against" doesn't mean "not", and any negative sentence it has is applied to "stealing", not "prohibition". It is at most a negative concord. Just because a word "goes with" negative senses doesn't make it a negative. For instance, consider "There are some" versus "There are not any". When you switch from positive to negative, "some" changes to "any". That doesn't mean that "any" is a negative, or that "There are not any" is a double negative.

Comment: You could give an example of a double negstive, so the OP can compare

Comment: @Mari-LouA you mean like [this one](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/bb/23/07/bb2307f1f39e86b0b12dd6ec6f9f39ad.jpg)?